# When does Heroku update its gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I know that my local machine and Heroku are using the same version of the gem, but I'm wondering if it's possible that Heroku hasn't grabbed the latest bug fix tracked [here](http://www.github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/323).

Is it possible that my local machine has a newer `delayed_job 3.0.0` gem than Heroku does? The fix was committed on the 12th.

**When does Heroku update its gems?**

This seems likely because I can send email from my local rails app, but on Heroku, I run into problems detailed in the link [above](http://www.github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/323). I'm on the `bamboo-mri-1.9.2` stack btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It short, it doesn't.**  If you're using Bundler you're stipulating which versions are used in your Gemfile (which in turn defines version numbers in your Gemfile.lock, both of which should be committed to Git).

If you're not using Bundler, and are still using the .gems file at the root of your project, Heroku will use the most recent it has, unless you define a different version in which case it will use that.

More info can be found here:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gems

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to specify a git repository in your Gemfile.

e.g.,

```
gem "delayed_job", :git => "git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git", :ref => "80ca31f9eb"
```

using the commit with the fix.
(edit: wrong git repo, whoops.)

Comment: Thanks @mjhoy, this fixed my problem. I'm still not 100% on whether or not my hypothesis about different `delayed_job 3.0.0`s is correct though....